# Many to many relationships - Moving data from many tables to a single table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with users and one with labels
A label can have many users and a user can have many labels, so a Many to Many relationship
A joining table is needed, that's why I have label_user

Below you can see pictures of what they contain with example data:

Users:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5E6O.png

Labels:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NFjq.png

label_user:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW2Uo.png

Let's say I have 5000 users and I can sort them by gender. Let's say 2800 of them are males, how can I assign them all to a label?

Here's some things I tried:

```
public function add_users_to_label($label_id, $condition, $value)
{
    $db = new Database();

    $conn = $db->db_connect();

    $label_id = escape_string($conn, $label_id);

        $query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `label_user`(`label_id`, `user_id`) SELECT :label_id, psid FROM `iris_messenger_users` WHERE $condition = $value");

        $query->bind_param("iss", $label_id, $condition, $value);

        if ($query->execute()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return "Error inserting data: " . $conn->error . "\n";
        }

}
```

On the user side I have a simple form with select that let's you select a label and then this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['label-select'])) {

if ($_GET['show_only_gender'] == 'male') {
    $condition = 'gender';

    $user->add_users_to_label($_POST['label-select'], $condition, $_GET['show_only_gender']);
}
```

}

Basically, I want to get all users that are male and assign them to a label and put that into label_user with respectively the label_id and the user_id(psid)

Even if this worked I'd still have to do it 2699 times more. What can I do here to optimize and make it to run with 1 query if possible? 
I don't think using foreach and running it as much times as there are users is the best option, is it?

Is there any better approach I can take to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Although what you are describing does not make sense to have a "label" associated with a person for this specific component, the gender is already on the user table you should be able to get all male based on

select * from user where gender = 'male'

no need to JOIN to a label table on this field.  Similarly if you were trying to find people based on a name starting with something... you would not create a label for the name either.  Query directly from the table that has that specific component association.

Now, to answer your question, how to insert into the label table for each instance in bulk, you could do something like...  I am doing this based on some label ID = 123 as just an example in your labels table that represents gender.

I am doing a LEFT-JOIN in the select so we dont try to add for any user IDs that are already on file do not try to get re-added.

```
insert into label_user
  ( label_id,
    user_id )
  select 
         123 as label_id, 
         U.id as user_id
      from
         users U
            left join label_user LU
               on U.id = LU.user_id
               AND LU.label_id = 123
      where
             U.gender = 'male'
         AND LU.user_id IS NULL
```

You obviously need to adjust for php.